# Free unmanaged c-code memory in managed C#

Tags: c#, memory, unmanaged

I have a large c-code library that used to write its results to file.  I converted it to return it's data via a float* array to a C++ program like such (to avoid constant file I/O):

```
float* mgrib(...)
```

This worked fine in c++ where I could "free" the memory.  I managed to get the data into C# properly via:

```
IntPtr pointer = mgrib(...);
float[] result = new float[ size ];
Marshal.Copy( pointer, result, 0, size );
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem( pointer );
```

This is within a loop as many fields must be pulled from the function.  If it's less than 256 fields it works great.  If it's more it crashes without warning.  If I run a file through it properly then run another (totaling more than 256) it crashes.  I'm far from a CS expert but the 256 seems like more than a coincidence.

I appreciate any insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, are you sure the C++ library allocates the return-value buffer using `CoTaskMemAlloc`, so that you can free it using `Marshall.FreeCoTaskMem`? There are [various memory (de)allocation functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366533.aspx) and you cannot freely mix them.

That is the reason why libraries are very often designed to allocate and deallocate memory “on a single side”, e.g. use something like

```
void mgrib(..., float *buff, int buffsize);
```

Comment: The library is actually c code.  It was allocated with malloc (Can I allocate with CoTaskMemAlloc in c?).  From what I read online FreeCoTaskMem is compatible with malloc, but I'm over my head on topics like these.  Thanks for the response.